# Localization is not working with storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have gone through many code and links for Localization. I have set multiple language for my app. Especially if i select any language it does not change. It is always showing English.

For that I have created the string file from resource and through the base internalization I have set the language. Inside the implementation part I have set the code for the localization string.

Even when I am debugging with breakpoints it is still giving English. So if anyone gives a solution for this I highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you put breakpoints to debug storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes now i got answer.What i did was

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{

   app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  if(app.currentLanguage==ENGLISH)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==TAMIL)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ta-IN" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==SPANISH)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"es" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==FRENCH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==JAPANESE)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ja" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==GERMAN)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"de" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==KOREAN)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ko" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==RUSSIAN)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ru" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==HINDI)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE)
      path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hans" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==ITALIAN)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"it" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==PORTUGUESE)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pt" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==THAI)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==MALAY)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ms" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==INDONESIAN)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"id" ofType:@"lproj"];

  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE1)
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hant" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else
   {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
   }
 NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
 NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    return str; }

 In above coding since i gave nil for table[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil],it does not chnage.   

 After changing  In  NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizeSTRING"],it works.First  i gave nil instead of table:@"LocalizeSTRING".Once i gave localization string file name to table:@"LocalizeSTRING", it changes to language that what language i selected for STORYBOARD.                

 As i did not give localization string file name to table,nothing happened.But when it comes to xib we don't need to give string file name to table[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil].If we give nil only to table,it is accepatable for XIB.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed this tutorial some weeks ago, and now every thing works with my apps. This is really helpful and a good start to know how it all works.

Make sure you check the `Use Base Internationalization`. And a suggestion is the Base Language is English. Base is used when there is no Localization for like "Japanese, Korean, ...", so that is the language that everyone would understand English.

[Link to it!](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)

Comment: so what can i change for other language kets?

Comment: Normally that should work. Try cleaning your xCode cache `Product - Clean`
Otherwise send a screenshot of your hierarchy so I can look at it

Comment: kets tell me your maid id.I will send my project.

Comment: @user3182143 Put in on Mega, or another file host

Comment: tell me your gmail id.

Comment: @user3182143 put it on here the zip file: `http://mega.co.nz` i am not giving gmail id's

Comment: k kets i will do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54335/discussion-between-user3182143-and-kets).

Answer (score 0):

Now be clear what you need to localize, there are 2 kind of localizations:

**Dynamic localizations**, which you can use them in your program by typing `NSLocalizedString(@"key",@"Message")`;. They can be used by presenting an `AlertView`, or changing a `UILabel` dynamically, etc.

1. Create a new file, .string and call it `Localizable.strings`.
2. Go to file inspector, hit the localize button and choose base localization. (Now there will be shown your selected languages, which you can edit by hitting you project, and info)
3. Now you can you expand localizable.string and see you selected language. In the base localization you can add lines to `"key" = "english";`, in another for example italian you have to add `"key" = "inglese";`.
4. When you are done adding your lines then you just can get it, like this `NSString *language = NSLocalizedString(@"key",@"Message");`

**Static localizations** called also the Storyboard Localization which you need to localize, are easier than this. They provide an efficient way, by extracting all the strings from objects that you have used there. Example to tell you how to localize it:

1. Insert a label on a viewController of your storyboard, change it's title to "Great".
2. Click on your storyboard, at the files panel, go on the right panel, at file inspector and click localize. A pop will show telling you what to localize, you choose base.
3. Now suppose that you have added 1 language to the project (Italian). On your file inspector, select italian, and right now, by expanding storyboard at file inspector, you will see that there is generated also a storyboard.string italian. Open it
4. There you will see the the label name "Great". Change it to "Grande"
5. Now run your project, if the language of the phone is not italian, it will load the label with title "Great".
6. Try to change your phone's language to italian, run the project again and see what happens. The label shown has the title "Grande"

This was a short way to do this, but you can refer to this steps and the first answer that provided the link. You are doing something wrong, so read it with care. Hope it helps

Comment: 3rld i did everything what you told doing.But it wont work for me.